# Control inside repeater causing full postback even after keeping in update panel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, repeater

In my page, I have one search button and a repeater. I have wrapped everything inside `UpdatePanel`. My search button do not causes full postback, i.e ideal but `RadioButtonList` inside `Repeater` control does. I have no idea what to do.

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
           <table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" class="tabmn6">
             <tr id="trheader" runat="server">
               <th id="trEdit" runat="server">Edit</th>
               <th>User Name </th>
               <th>Role</th>
               <th>From Date</th>
               <th>To Date</th>
               <th>Comment</th>
               <th>Status</th>
             </tr>
             <asp:Repeater ID="rpUserDetails" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpUserDetails_ItemDataBound">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                      <tr>
                          <td id="tdRPEdit" runat="server" align="center">
                          <input type="button" class="editbtn" name="btnEdit" id="btnEdit" runat="server" onclick='<%# string.Format("javascript:return AddBoardCast(\"{0},{1}\")", Eval("BC_ID"),"Edit") %>'>
                          </td>
                          <td id="trRPTL" runat="server" align="center">
                                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblUName" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text='<%#Eval("UserName")%>' />
                         </td>
                         <td align="center">
                         <asp:Label ID="lblRoleName" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text='<%#Eval("RoleName")%>' />
                       </td>
                   <td align="center">
                   <asp:Label ID="lblToDate" runat="server" ForeColor="Black"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BC_FromDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%></asp:Label>
                   </td>
                   <td align="center"><asp:Label ID="lblFromDate" runat="server" ForeColor="Black"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BC_TODate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%></asp:Label></td>
                  <td align="center" width="20%">
                    <div style="color: black"><%#Eval("BC_Comment")%></div>
                   </td>
                   <td align="center">
                  <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnBC_ID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("BC_ID") %>' />
                  <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnUserID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("UserID") %>' />
                   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdStatus" runat="server" Height="48px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="rad">
                          <asp:ListItem Text="Active" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                           <asp:ListItem Text="Deactive" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
           </td>
    </tr>
                                                                </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
 </table>
 </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```